# Display the checkboxes selected into a section and the unselected into another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show the checkboxes selected into a div but actually I have a duplicate item in the list and I'm not sure how to display the unselected items into another div.

You can try out here http://jsfiddle.net/tedjimenez/7wzR5/

Here my code:

```
JS CODE

/* Array */
    var list = new Array("valuetext000", "valuetext001", "valuetext002", "valuetext003", "valuetext004", "valuetext005", "valuetext006", "valuetext007", "valuetext008", "valuetext009", "valuetext010", "valuetext011", "valuetext012", "valuetext013", "valuetext014", "valuetext015", "valuetext016", "valuetext017")

    var html = "";

    /* Array will be converted to an ul list */

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        html += "<input type='checkbox' name='boxvalue' value='" + list[i] + "' /><label>" + list[i] + "</label><br>";
    }

    $("#elmAv").append(html);
```

THE HTML CODE

```
<form>
    <div id="elmAv"></div>
    <div id="selectionResult"></div>
    <script>
        /* Function to display the items selected */
         function showBoxes(frm) {
            var checkedItems = "\n";
            //For each checkbox see if it has been checked, record the value.
            for (i = 0; i < frm.boxvalue.length; i++) {
                if (frm.boxvalue[i].checked) {
                    checkedItems = checkedItems + "<li>" + frm.boxvalue[i].value + "<li>";
                }
            }
            $("#elmAv").empty();
            $("#selectionResult").append(checkedItems);
        }
    </script>
    <input type="Button" value="Get Selection" onClick="showBoxes(this.form)" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add another div after selectionResult like this:

```
<div id="unselectedResult"></div>
```

And then update showBoxes() with the following code:

```
function showBoxes(frm) {
    var checkedItems = "Checked:<br>\n";
    var uncheckedItems = "Unchecked:<br>\n";
    //For each checkbox see if it has been checked, record the value.
    for (i = 0; i < frm.boxvalue.length; i++) {
        if (frm.boxvalue[i].checked) {
            checkedItems = checkedItems + "<li>" + frm.boxvalue[i].value + "</li>";
        }
        else {
            uncheckedItems = uncheckedItems + "<li>" + frm.boxvalue[i].value + "</li>";
        }
    }
    $("#elmAv").empty();
    $("#selectionResult").append(checkedItems);
    $('#unselectedResult').append(uncheckedItems);
}
```

Should get the result you're looking for.

Comment: Updated - Thanks so much! Do you have any idea why is duplicating the items with a empty value? try to choose a item then click on get selection. http://jsfiddle.net/tedjimenez/7wzR5/1/

Comment: Just noticed the `</li>` tag was missing. Updated the code in my answer. It may fix the duplication issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  Added another array listChecked to track checked values.

```
<script>
/* Array */
var list = new Array("valuetext000", "valuetext001", "valuetext002", "valuetext003", "valuetext004", "valuetext005", "valuetext006", "valuetext007", "valuetext008", "valuetext009", "valuetext010", "valuetext011", "valuetext012", "valuetext013", "valuetext014", "valuetext015", "valuetext016", "valuetext017")

var listChecked = new Array();

$(document).ready(function() {
    displayUnchecked();
});
/* Array will be converted to an ul list */
function displayUnchecked()
{
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if ($.inArray(list[i], listChecked) == -1)
            html += "<input type='checkbox' name='boxvalue' value='" + list[i] + "' /><label>" + list[i] + "</label><br>";
    }

    $("#elmAv").html(html);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>                                                
<form>
<div id="elmAv"></div>
<div id="selectionResult"></div>
<script>

/* Display the items selected */

function showBoxes(frm) {
    var checkedItems = "\n";
    //alert('here');
    //For each checkbox see if it has been checked, record the value.
    for (i = 0; i < frm.boxvalue.length; i++) {
        if (frm.boxvalue[i].checked) {
            listChecked.push(frm.boxvalue[i].value);
        }
    }

    $.each(listChecked, function (index, value)
            {
                checkedItems = checkedItems + "<li>" + value + "</li>";
            });
    //alert('here');
    displayUnchecked();
    //$("#elmAv").empty();
    $("#selectionResult").html(checkedItems);
}
</script>
<input type="Button" value="Get Selection" onClick="showBoxes(this.form)" />
</form>                                 
</body>
```